# Best way to secure a second Linux server with SSL used only to serve files

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https

I have my main HTTP server which has a SSL cert for my website, all is good. I have invested in a second server (higher bandwidth) to serve my downloads so the main HTTP server isn't being bogged down with download bandwidth.

My question is how do I serve those files over HTTPS on the second server? It doesn't have a domain tied to it, I'm simply pointing at the IP for the download links.

The servers are in separate data centers if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

If your main site is `www.example.com` simply off-load (big) downloads and other content to a subdomain that points to your second server. Common names would be `static.example.com`, `content.example.com`, `download(s).example.com`, etc. you get the idea :) Arrange a corresponding TLS certificate and Bob's your uncle

Comment: Especially with cheap (as in free beer) certs from let's encrypt!